# Google Maps - Drag marker, GetPosition returning same position always

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I have a for loop which creates more than 100 markers. When I drag a random marker I get always the same position written in the console. But the "Point" value is different when I drag another marker. So the question is why I am getting always the same position? If I try with only 1 marker, the code is working.

Piece of code:

```
coordinates.forEach(function(entry) {   

    if(!isOdd(number)){
        marker_lat = entry;
        number++;
    }else{
        marker_lng = entry;             
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker_lat),parseFloat(marker_lng));

        marker_icon = "red.png";

          mark = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myLatlng,
           map: map,
           title: number,
           icon: marker_icon,  
           draggable:true
         });                
        number++;

        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function() { 
                id_point = $(this).attr("title");
                console.log("Point: "+id_point);
                console.log(mark.getPosition().lat());// Always the same position
                console.log(mark.getPosition().lng());// Always the same position
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `this.getPosition().lat()`?  I haven't tested this, but if the listener is fired using the activated mark as the calling context of the function, it should work as is.  I'm just can't remember if that's how google does it in this listener.

Comment: Correction: I was wrong.  You have to pass it as a parameter.  I'll add an answer.

Comment: Second correction: my first shot-in-the-dark guess was also correct.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker is passed as a parameter to the function by the listener.  Try this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function(m) { 
    id_point = $(this).attr("title");
    console.log("Point: "+id_point);
    console.log(m.latLng.lat());
    console.log(m.latLng.lng()); /* different from your
                                    code.  Can't really
                                    test right now, but
                                    this seems to work on
                                    the last project I
                                    did. */
});
```

In addition to this, you can also call `getPosition()` on `this`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'dragend', function(m) { 
    id_point = this.title;
    console.log("Point: "+id_point);
    console.log(this.getPosition().lat()); // same as below
    console.log(m.latLng.lat());
});
```

Comment: I get an error "m.getPosition is not a function" :/

Comment: If you'll notice, I updated my answer to include the correct code.  Here's a demo of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/cjw2stk4/